# Get frames of a video on a web-page

Tags: javascript, iis, video, canvas

There is a video of a diamond represented as a sequence of images. Here is the link: http://beta.jamesallen.com/#!/loose-diamonds/Round-cut/0.70-carat-K-color-SI1-clarity-Very-Good-cut-sku-163685. If asked about credentials, you can use `fsgs2k@gmail.com` / `hello` as login / password.

The video is displayed inside a `canvas` element by some tricky JS. I'm not experienced enough to go though this controlling JS. What I want is:

- Find out at what frame rate this video is shown. Is it 25 fps?
- Get the underlying image sequence.

I need your help with these tasks.

Comment: Open it in chrome, F12, resources, frames, site, images

Comment: @AlexK. That's great! Is there a way to batch-save all these images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the resource folder displayed in the `<canvas>` element :

```
<canvas id="diamond_s1" class="diamondCanvas" style="display: block;" 
setfolder="Sets/Diamond/$number/sets/" width="473" height="375"></canvas>
```

You have to get that folder path, and then you should be able to make requests to the urls you can see in the tab Network of Chrome that contains the previous dir and ends [with set[number].txt](http://cdn2.jamesallen.com/Sets/Diamond/163685/sets/set1.txt)

These url return the whole video frame by frame encoded as bsae64 data-image. You'll get a lot of `data:image/jpeg;base64,` followed by the base64 image. That's the image frame you have to get and convert in jpeg via simple base64 decoding

You'll have to figure out in which order they're taken, but the json gives you some insights about that

Comment: I have a problem with your solution: the link http://cdn2.jamesallen.com/Sets/Diamond/163685/sets/set11.txt is the last working link, and the link http://cdn2.jamesallen.com/Sets/Diamond/163685/sets/set12.txt gives an exception. However, there are much more that 11 images in the video. Where are the rest of the frames?

Comment: Oh, I get it, every file encodes not one, but a couple of images. Now need to figure out how to extract all of them.

Comment: Oh, they are just in a comma-separated list. Thanks a lot for your help!